# When will Facebook Graph Search be available for me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-search

I've clicked to join the beta for [Facebook Graph Search](https://www.facebook.com/about/graphsearch), but I still cannot access the feature.

[image]

When will it be rolled out to the public? Is there any way to circumvent the "beta wall" and gain access now?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Facebook Graph Search was retired. Related: [A task for the task jar: Clean up facebook questions and tags as they are bumped by Community user](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5152/88163)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [press release](http://newsroom.fb.com/News/562/Introducing-Graph-Search-Beta):

> The roll out is going to be slow so we can see how people use Graph
>   Search and make improvements.

and

> **How are you rolling this out?** 
>   Graph Search is in a limited preview, or beta. That means Graph Search will only be available to a very small number of people who use Facebook in US English.
>
> **How can I get Facebook Graph Search?** 
>   You can sign up for the waitlist at www.facebook.com/graphsearch

As the button you clicked says, you've joined a waiting list for the beta. Facebook will be very slow and cautious rolling this out, the world is watching.